# How to Create Multiple Window in Same Browser Screen?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to know, how can I create Multiple Windows Like Chat windows in Facebook which opens inside Browser and can be minimized, maximized or Close and Look like Window Explorer?

Comment: I have no Idea about this Pranav? I asked to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "multiple windows" that you say are not actually windows but, just html page elements mostly enclosed inside a div, the minimized, maximized and close buttons are actually simple images or css styles that has a javascript function set to run when you click them, there are some implementations available on the web like [Gmail/Facebook style jquery chat](http://anantgarg.com/2009/05/13/gmail-facebook-style-jquery-chat/)

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite vague, however if you want to implement mini window kind of controls on your page, it depends on what data you show in them and how you show.

you can use Div tags to resemble / look alike windows in a small screen, and if your page is written in such way that it can handle ajax requests and show content, you can directly show content inside Div, or if you have a seperate page to show the content, you can load the content in an iframe which resides inside the Div.
    
        Place your controls here

you can position the div using Css and content via javascript

Comment: Thanks it helped a lot. Do you have any sample for holding normal data, means not PostBack and server requests?